# Week number to Month number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date with this format : 14w01 (year : 2014  week number : 1)

I want to convert this date in month like this : 14m01
Is there a function which converts a week number in a month number ?

Maybe something like this (in vba, not in formula) :

```
Format(weekNumber, "mm")
```

Thank you

Comment: Is that actually a `Date`, or is it a `String` in a cell that you need to parse?

Comment: **Many weeks can span 2 months**  Do you want the **Monday** of the week and then the month of that Monday??

Comment: Or are you trying to make it week 1-5 = Jan, week 6-9 = Feb and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the weeks are defined.  One way is to say that the first day of week#1 of a year is 1 January of that year.  For this definition, a typical *UDF* is:

```
Public Function MonthFromDt(s As String) As Integer
    Dim yr As Integer, wk As Integer, d As Date
    ary = Split(s, "w")
    yr = CInt(ary(0)) + 2000
    wk = ary(1)
    MonthFromDt = Month(DateSerial(yr, 1, 1) + 7 * (wk - 1))
End Function
```

*There are other definitions of week number.*

Answer (score 1):

The `DateFormat` function is quiet comfortable, however the `DateValue` function, which parses a date, won't probably support your week format.

I suggest a trick with `DateAdd`, as `DateAdd` can handle weeks.

First split your date in year and week number:

```
Dim parts
parts = Split("2014w33", "w")

Dim year
Dim week
year = CInt(parts(0))
week = CInt(parts(1))
```

Then, add both to a "zero-date" to add up to the final date. Note that if you give "0" as year for `DateAdd`, VBA compiler interprets 2000.

```
dim DateResult

DateResult = dateAdd("yyyy", (year - 2000), DateValue("Jan 1, 0"))
Debug.Print dateResult

DateResult = dateAdd("ww", week, dateResult)
Debug.Print dateResult
```

Then show the result reformatted:

```
Debug.Print Format(DateResult, "yyyy\mm")
```

This prints on my side:

```
01.01.2014 
20.08.2014 
2014m08
```

August 2014, there is week 33 if I look up in the calendar. Seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it without VBA (and only using Formulas). This assumes A1 contains the "14w01" format

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&"m"&TEXT(MONTH(DATE(20&LEFT(A1,2),1,1)+(RIGHT(A1,2)*7)),"00")
```

Heres a breakdown of what the code does..

`LEFT(A1,2)` returns "14" (year)

`MONTH(DATE(20&LEFT(A1,2),1,1)+(RIGHT(A1,2)*7))` converts the week # to the month # and it takes in the year `20&LEFT(A1,2)` as well as week # `RIGHT(A1,2)`

`TEXT(...,"00")` pads the month # with a 0 if necessary (i.e. 3 becomes 03)

Then we just combine everything together to get "14m01"